# Bows in ShadowRun: How do I calculate the damage?

Tags: shadowrun-sr4

In the SR4 rulebook 20th Anniversary edition, Bows damage assisted as `(STR min+2)p` yet later on, in the rulebook it says to calculate the base damage as the lowest of the bow and arrow rating.

To clarify, this is the relavent  text:

> Bows have minimum strength ratings that indicate the minimum Strength a character must have to use that weapon....The weapon's minimum Strength rating is also used to determine the weapon's range and damage. Material science limits high-tech bows to a maximum strength rating of 8. Calculate base damage using the lower value of the bow rating and arrow rotting.

Now, that leaves me scratching my head. Is that to say the bow damage is `(STR min+2+rating)p`? Or is through damage listed in the table for a rating 2 bow? That would make the bow damage `(STR min+rating)p` where rating is the minimum of the bow and arrow rating?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is to say that the your DV is a minimum of (arrow rating, bow base DV).

Bow base DV is confusing. First, STR min = bow rating. Second, it was listed in different printings as (STR min) + 2P and as (STR min)P; I personally go with the former. Third, rating is capped at 8 (or at 6 during chargen). Fourth, total bow damage (net hits included) is capped at 1.5xrating (don't remember a source on this one, though; I personally don't use this rule anyway).

**So, the base DV of a bow shot is a minimum of (arrow rating, bow rating + 2)P.**

Comment: I've seen people saying that before, but i can't trace down where it says that in my rules version, the 20th anniversary edition. Could you give me page numbers?

Comment: @Pureferret Well, p315 in the Bows table. Damage is (STR Min +2)P, and STR Min = Rating.

Comment: @Schoolmaster What about the 1.5*rating cap? And also, where does it state that STR min = rating, or should that just be infered?

Comment: @Pureferret the same page, description of the bow, says "Bows have minimum Strength ratings, ...". 1.5*rating cap is said to be mentioned in German printing of Arsenal (not necessarily first) or in the errata for it (along with the ratings for arrows), but I don't have access to German books.

Comment: So the implication is: STR Rating = STR Min = Rating? I'm just very used to this sort of quibble being spelled out in other RPG books I've read.

Comment: @Pureferret Yup, STR Rating = STR Min = Rating in that description, it is a bit awkward now that I think about it. As for the 1.5*rating cap, it is mentioned on p315-316 of 20th Anniversary Edition.

Comment: @Scrollmaster where on the page? Are we referencing the same version of that book?

Comment: @Pureferret as I said, 20th Anniversary Edition. After verification, yup, nothing about a damage cap in the "basic" book

Comment: @Scrollmaster perhaps you could either edit this answer, or post your own, for clarity? Is the Damage `Min(Bow,Arrow)` rating or `Min(Str Min +2,Arrow)` or...?